# Test including redirect_to fails with rspec but application is working as expected. Chapter 9.6.6 of Michael Hartl book (v 4.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to solve a problem 6 of chapter 9.6 of Michael Hartl book Rails v 4.0.

Though everything looks fine in rspec test:

```
  describe "should redirect a logged in user to root url if user tries to hit new in users controller" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    before do
      sign_in user
      get new_user_path
    end

    specify{expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
  end

  describe "should redirect a logged in user to root url if user tries to hit create in users controller" do
    let(:params) do {user: {name: "Tester", email: "test@example.com", password: "password",
                            password_confirmation: "password"}}
    end
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

    before do
      sign_in user
      post users_path, params
    end

    specify{expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
  end
```

And here is my controller snippet:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :is_signed_in, only: [:new, :create]
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

 private
  def is_signed_in
    redirect_to(root_url) if signed_in?
  end
end
```

sign_in method in utilities.rb

```
def sign_in(user, options = {})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Signin when not using capybara
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign In"
  end
end
```

But my testcases are failing with following errors:

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication signin with valid information should redirect a logged in user to root url if user tries to hit create in users controller
   Failure/Error: specify{expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/2>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/users/2".
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:69:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin with valid information should redirect a logged in user to root url if user tries to hit new in users controller
 Failure/Error: specify{expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
   Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:55:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.22 seconds
95 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:69 # Authentication signin with valid information should redirect a logged in user to root url if user tries to hit create in users controller
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:55 # Authentication signin with valid information should redirect a logged in user to root url if user tries to hit new in users controller

Randomized with seed 58509
```

I tried to debug, but not able to figure out exact problem. Can anyone help me on this ?

**EDIT: 1: Added route.rb**
Routes.rb

```
    SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
      resources :users
      resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
      root "static_pages#home"
      match '/help', to: "static_pages#help", via: 'get'
      match '/about', to: "static_pages#about", via: 'get'
      match '/contact', to: "static_pages#contact", via: 'get'
      match '/signup', to: "users#new", via: 'get'
      match '/signin', to: "sessions#new", via: 'get'
      match '/signout', to: "sessions#destroy", via: 'delete'
   end
```

**EDIT 2**
I'm testing it with capybara.

Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '<1.1.0'
  gem "launchy", "2.3.0"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
end
```

session_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    current_user == user
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How is our `root` defined in the `routes.rb`?

Comment: And I suggest to add temporary something like `puts "signed in: #{is_signed_in}` into our `is_signed_in` method. Just to find out if your `sign_in` helper method really logs in a user for the test.

Comment: Are you testing with or without Capybara? Also, would you mind sharing your `signed_in?` method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing this:

```
no_capybara: true
```

So it should look like this:

```
before do
  sign_in user, no_capybara: true
  get new_user_path
end
```

and this:

```
before do
  sign_in user, no_capybara: true
  post users_path, params
end
```

This is the only difference between what I have vs. yours. Hope it works!